# d3.js extend bottom axis line to origin

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'd like to space the first tick from the origin point, but would also like to have a line connecting them. I suppose I could append an svg to do this for me, but there has to be an easier way that I am missing in the documentation. An image example of what I'm aiming for can be found [here](https://pasteboard.co/H0vaVqm.png)

Here's an example of the issue I'm having:

```js
var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 10,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 40
     };
    
     var padding = 20;
    
     var height = 100;
     var width = 400
    
      var xAxisTimeScale = [];
    
      for(var i = 8; i < 21; i++) {
       xAxisTimeScale.push(i);
      }
    
      // scales
      var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 12])
      .range([padding, width - padding]);
    
      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 10])
      .range([height, 0]);
    
     function convertTimeToString(time) {
      if(time > 12) {
       return (time - 12) + "PM";
      } else {
       return time + "AM";
      }
     }
    
     var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
     .ticks(13)
     .tickFormat(function(d,i){ return convertTimeToString(xAxisTimeScale[i]);});
    
     var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
    
     var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
     .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
     .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
     // add axes
     svg.append('g')
     .call(yAxis);
    
     svg.append('g')
     .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
     .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please use the native snippet tool instead of JSBin

Comment: Done, thanks @DavidStockinger, I didn't know that was an option.

Comment: Does changing the xScale's range from `.range([padding, width - padding]);` to `.range([0, width - padding]);` serve the purpose? I'm not sure what do you mean by **have a line connecting them**.

Comment: @Shashank - No, that moves the first tick to the origin point, but thanks for the suggestion! I've uploaded an image to show what I'm talking about [here](https://pasteboard.co/H0vaVqm.png)

Comment: Yeah right! I thought that's what you needed by reading the question at a glance. Yep, got it, thanks for the image.

Comment: Okay. I've created a couple of fiddles with the requirement fulfilled. I'll post them in an hour or so with a neat explanation (after I get off work), alright?

Comment: I added an ad hoc solution. If @Shashank can provide an idiomatic solution I'll delete mine (ad hoc solutions are ugly and cumbersome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the approaches I came up with:

1. Change x axis's `path`'s `d` attribute to `'M0,0.5V0.5H'+(width-padding)`. Relevant code changes:

   ```
   svg.select('.x.axis path.domain').attr('d', function() {
       return 'M0,0.5V0.5H'+(width-padding);
   });
   ```

   How did I come up with `0.5` in there? I analyzed [d3.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.6.0/d3.js) and came across the `V0.5` (which was `V0` in **d3-version3** used for creating X-axis domain. For more details on how a path is formed, check out [SVG path d attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d). Using this offset, here's a code snippet implementing the same:

   ```js
   var margin = {
         top: 20,
         right: 10,
         bottom: 40,
         left: 40
        };
       
        var padding = 20;
       
        var height = 100;
        var width = 400
       
         var xAxisTimeScale = [];
       
         for(var i = 8; i < 21; i++) {
          xAxisTimeScale.push(i);
         }
       
         // scales
         var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
         .domain([0, 12])
         .range([padding, width - padding]);
       
         var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
         .domain([0, 10])
         .range([height, 0]);
       
        function convertTimeToString(time) {
         if(time > 12) {
          return (time - 12) + "PM";
         } else {
          return time + "AM";
         }
        }
       
        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .ticks(13)
        .tickFormat(function(d,i){ return convertTimeToString(xAxisTimeScale[i]);});
       
        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
       
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
       
        // add axes
        svg.append('g')
        .call(yAxis);
       
        svg.append('g').classed('x axis', true)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);
        
        svg.select('.x.axis path.domain').attr('d', function() {
          return 'M0,0.5V0.5H'+(width-padding);
        });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Add a line explicitly from **origin** to the **start-point** of X-axis with a simple line code. Relevant code changes:

   ```
   svg.append('line').classed('connecting-line', true)
   .attr('y1', height+0.5).attr('y2', height+0.5).attr('x1', 0).attr('x2', padding).style('stroke', '#000');
   ```

   `0.5` has the same reason as above. Rest attributes are just based on height and width. Here's a code snippet implementing this:

   ```js
   var margin = {
         top: 20,
         right: 10,
         bottom: 40,
         left: 40
        };
       
        var padding = 20;
       
        var height = 100;
        var width = 400
       
         var xAxisTimeScale = [];
       
         for(var i = 8; i < 21; i++) {
          xAxisTimeScale.push(i);
         }
       
         // scales
         var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
         .domain([0, 12])
         .range([padding, width - padding]);
       
         var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
         .domain([0, 10])
         .range([height, 0]);
       
        function convertTimeToString(time) {
         if(time > 12) {
          return (time - 12) + "PM";
         } else {
          return time + "AM";
         }
        }
       
        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .ticks(13)
        .tickFormat(function(d,i){ return convertTimeToString(xAxisTimeScale[i]);});
       
        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
       
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
       
        // add axes
        svg.append('g')
        .call(yAxis);
       
        svg.append('g').classed('x axis', true)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);
     
      svg.append('line').classed('connecting-line', true)
        .attr('y1', height+0.5).attr('y2', height+0.5).attr('x1', 0).attr('x2', padding).style('stroke', '#000');
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>
   ```
3. Adding an overlay rectangle either as a **box** OR as a rect styled with `stroke-dasharray`. But I think this wouldn't be that helpful as it would be a bit of overriding stuff.

Hope any of the above approaches serves the purpose. And I'm really sorry for not getting back on time (Friday night got me) :)

Comment: @Gerardo I'd appreciate if you could comment on the above approaches. I've been reading almost every answer of yours since a month now and trying to improve myself. Thanks.

Comment: They are creative approaches, indeed... However, they are just as *ad hoc* as mine!

Comment: @Shashank - I accepted your answer as it gives a few options, but Gerardo's answer is great too! Thanks so much to you both. I'd though about both approaches (increasing domain + removing first tick, adding/extending an svg) but was hoping the library would have something a bit more standard. You guys rock!

Comment: Glad I could help! I did actually look up in the library if it had anything ready-made for this but couldn't find anything. Anyway, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a linear scale disguised as a time scale, the solution here will be an **ad hoc** one. Otherwise, the solution could be more idiomatic.

First, increase your `xAxisTimeScale`:

```
var xAxisTimeScale = d3.range(7, 23, 1)
```

Then, increase your domain...

```
.domain([0, 13])
```

... and remove the first tick:

```
.tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    return i ? convertTimeToString(xAxisTimeScale[i]) : null;
});
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 40
};

var padding = 20;

var height = 100;
var width = 400

var xAxisTimeScale = d3.range(7, 23, 1)

// scales
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 13])
  .range([0, width - padding]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range([height, 0]);

function convertTimeToString(time) {
  if (time > 12) {
    return (time - 12) + "PM";
  } else {
    return time + "AM";
  }
}

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .ticks(13)
  .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    return i ? convertTimeToString(xAxisTimeScale[i]) : null;
  });

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// add axes
svg.append('g')
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
  .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @gerardo-furtado! Both of you haver some creative solutions.